# Сгруппировать данные, ограничив выборку по значениям определенного поля

Tags: sql, oracle-study

Нужно реализовать 2 запроса:

1. По данным из таблицы HR.EMPLOYEES сформировать список тех менеджеров, у которых в подчинении находится не менее 5 сотрудников. При формировании списка ограничиться департаментами с номерами 50 и 80.
2. По данным из таблицы HR.EMPLOYEES сформировать список должностей с указанием job_id, количества сотрудников, суммарной зарплаты и разницы между самой высокой и самой низкой зарплатой.

Попробовал первый:

```
select manager_id, count(*) as count_worker from HR.EMPLOYEES 
group by manager_id  
having count(*) > 5 and department_id = 50 and department_id = 80
```

Но выводит ошибку, со вторым даже пока нет идей как реализовать. Можете подсказать пожалуйста

Comment: По №2 - Очень сложно что ли бос казать, не видя примеров данных. Оформите отдельный вопрос с примером таблицы, данными, которые там содержаться и вашими попытками добиться нужного результата и желаемого результата.

Comment: Таблица данных - это базовая таблица от Oracle, встроена в sql live от оракла

Comment: От этого не легче

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкция **WHERE** должна идти после **FROM**

```
select manager_id, count(*) as count_worker 
from HR.EMPLOYEES 
where department_id in (50, 80)
group by manager_id  
having count(*) >= 5
```

**group by** - группировка по заданным полям
**having** - ограничение вывода сгруппированных результатов